# Escape developer name umlauts in a Maven POM file?

Tags: xml, maven, encoding

In the `<developers>` section of a `pom.xml`, if a name contains non-7-bit-ascii characters, e.g. German umlauts (`ä`) or French accents (`é`)—do I need to escape them somehow? Because if I view the file with Mozilla, I get an error:

```
XML Parsing Error: undefined entity

            <name>Foo B&eacute;r</name>
-----------------------^
```

Should I just type the accents as such and assume maven uses UTF-8 decoding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One cannot use HTML named entities in XML. Use UTF-8 and you get full WYSIWIG. If encoding is not listed in  it defaults to UTF-8.